# How to implement a generalized callback mechanism in C++03 without boost?

Tags: c++, callback

I have an http server that has a request handler like that :

```
bool handleRequest(const RequestObject& request, ResponseRequest& response);
```

I'm trying to write a wrapper that would provide an API like that :

```
addRouteHandler(GET, "/foo/bar", handler);
```

With `handler` able to be either :

1. a function : `bool handleFooBarRequest(const RequestObject& request, ResponseRequest& response);`
2. a method on an existing object : `FooResourceInstance` + `bool FooResource::handleFooBarRequest(const RequestObject& request, ResponseRequest& response);`
3. a static method of an object : `static bool FooResource::handleFooBarRequest(const RequestObject& request, ResponseRequest& response);`

I insist : C++03 (gcc 4.1.2) and no Boost (the reason is NOT the point)

So far the techniques I have found either use Boost, C++11 or third-party code (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/136799/Lightweight-Generic-C-Callbacks-or-Yet-Another-Del)

Comment: Implementing Functors is illustrated in chapter 5 of "Modern C++ Design", Andrei Alexandrescu, 2001.

Comment: Why not look at how Boost and other libraries work, and then implement something similar?

Comment: just copy the way boost does it?

Comment: Yep, Boost isn't magic.  It's code, just like the stuff you write.

Comment: Boost implementation would most likely rely on a lot of other Boost powerful features that I don't need for a simple implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an interface and a derived template class.  This technique is called "type erasure".

```
class CallbackBase
{
public:
    virtual ~CallbackBase() = 0;
    virtual bool exec(const RequestObject& request, ResponseRequest& response) = 0;
};

template <typename F>
class CallbackImpl : public CallbackBase
{
public:
    CallbackImpl(F f) : f_(f) {}
    virtual bool exec(const RequestObject& request, ResponseRequest& response) {
        return f_(request, response);
    }
private:
    F f_;
};

template <typename F>
void CreateCallback(F f, std::auto_ptr<CallbackBase>& r) {
    r.reset(new CallbackImpl<F>(f));
}

// examples
std::auto_ptr<CallbackBase> my_callback;

CreateCallback(GlobalFooBarRequest, my_callback);
CreateCallback(&FooResource::staticFooBarRequest, my_callback);
// for member function, use std::mem_fun and std::bind1st
...

my_callback->exec(request, response);
```

You might want to use a shared_ptr or similar instead of auto_ptr, all depends on how you want to store these objects.

Edit:
you can write your own member function wrapper/closure/function object.  Code would looks something like the following (I haven't tried compiling it so there could be some errors):

```
template <typename T>
class RequestWrapper
{
    typedef bool (T::*F)(const RequestObject&, ResponseRequest&);
    T* obj_;
    F f_;
public:
    RequestWrapper(T* obj, F f)
    : obj_(obj)
    , f_(f)
    {}

    bool operator()(const RequestObject& request, ResponseRequest& response) const {
        return (obj_->*f_)(request, response);
    }
};

template <typename T, typename F>
RequestWrapper<T> BindRequestMfn(T* obj, F mfn)
{
    return RequestWrapper<T>(obj, mfn);
}


CreateCallback(BindRequestMfn(foo, &FooResource::fooBarRequest), my_callback);
```

Comment: Works nice for cases 1 and 2. Mind a hint for third case ? (mem_fun/bind1st) I'm trying right now, but it's over my current level.

Comment: bind1st(mem_fun(&FooResource::handleFooBarRequest), ptr_to_object)).  Alternatively you could write your own wrapper using a template class.  Maybe its worth trying that out as you'd push your current level higher by trying.

Comment: That's what I thought : `error: no matching function for call to 'mem_fun(bool (FooResource::*)(const RequestObject&, ResponseRequest&))`. (I would really have questionned my sanity if it had worked) Isn't "improved" mem_fun a C++11 feature ?

Comment: A nice explanation of type erasure : http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/18756/

Comment: Do you need to specify the std namespace?  i.e.

Comment: Do you need to specify the std namespace?  i.e. std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(bool (FooResource::*)(const RequestObject&, ResponseRequest&))).  Or, write you own function object wrapper that contains the member function pointer and a pointer to the object.

Comment: the `std` namespace is used, it doesn't appear in the error. Remember that I have this C++03 `mem_fun` : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/mem_fun/ which show no prototype corresponding to your solution. I'm breaking it to smaller examples right now to try to understand the `mem_fun`/`bind1st` combo.

Comment: oh I see - I forgot that it only handled member functions with 0 arguments.

Comment: 0 or 1, yes. Here are my tests on the `mem_fun`/`bind1st` combo : https://gist.github.com/Offirmo/4713286. I learned a lot, thanks !

Comment: Added details on writing your own member function wrapper

Answer (score 1):

This solution described here fully works : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11015/The-Impossibly-Fast-C-Delegates

Only 3 headers.

C++03, gcc 4.1.2 OK and no Boost ; MIT license

Comment: Wait, so you can use other C++ libraries but no Boost? That’s simply a mad requirement.

Comment: So what if Boost is huge? On what kind of system does that matter (or rather, on what kind of system is the increased productivity provided by Boost negated by its large size)? And just dropping in the headers is as easy as pie.

Comment: Looks, I *totally* love Boost but some deciders in my company have *decided* no Boost for their own (mis-)reasons. 3 files, I can argue. Full Boost, I can't. My company has lot of other good points that make up for it.

Comment: Argh. Corporate policy. My favourite form of ignorance. :-( You have my sympathy.

Comment: @Offirmo what about the required boost subset? You don't have to copy the whole beast, you know. Also, what's the guarantee that the codeproject code is working correctly?

Comment: @Offirmo Y U NO BCP? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418918/using-boost-unordered-map/13423990#13423990

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz copying a subpart of Boost could be seen as playing fool. And I've tested codeproject solution of course, it works.

Comment: I didn't ask you to prove it worked once, when you tested it. It can have subtle errors inside that are hard to find. Does it have tests with it? Also, *what exactly* is wrong with copying parts of Boost? There are even boost tools for seeking dependencies in code and creating appropriate package for you (like [BCP](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html))

Comment: Thanks for the link anyhoops. Looks interesting enough